# 'myApp.controller is not a function' error in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm getting the following error in the js console log when attempting to assign the controller to 'myCtrl' variable in a jasmine test: 'myApp.controller is not a function'

In the controller itself, the controller is defined as the following and this is what's triggering the error I mentioned:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ...
```

And this is how I'm trying to access the controller in my spec file:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp');
});

it('tests the controller', inject(function($controller) {
    var myCtrl = $controller('myCtrl');
}));
```

Any idea why it's still throwing this error? Seems to be a missing dependency but not sure where..

Comment: is this your full test case ? If so that is not the proper way of writing a [jasmine style test case](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks - It turns out it was something as simple as I need to list myApp.js before myController.js in the SecRunner.html. I was pretty sure I tried that previously.. but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your controller , following is one way of writing a test case

```
describe('YourControllerName', function () {
    var $rootScope, scope, $controller   ;

   beforeEach(angular.mock.module('YourModuleName'));

   beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller ) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('YourControllerName', {
        $scope: scope
       }); 
    }));

    it('Should do this', function () {
        //assertions
    });
});
```